# Sci-fi short story about a machine composing music

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, music

I am looking for the name of a short story I read years ago.  I thought it was written by Philip K. Dick, but now I'm not so sure.

The story is about a music teacher who teaches students how to use a composing device to create music.  It seems to have made the old art of making music with actual humans obsolete.  An older student arrives who likes the old way of making music and hates the device.  The teacher convinces him to learn how to use it.

At the end of the story the student loves the device and what he can accomplish with its assistance.  The student has also devised a new way to automate the device, so that it can compose on its own.  The teacher destroys the plans for the upgraded device, but realizes the upgrade will arrive eventually, and when it does, humanity will no longer create music at all, as the machine will do it all for them.

Comment: Lol soon it will be off-topic ))

Comment: Can't find a link or a title but it sounds like a JG Ballard story ?

Comment: Do you have a rough estimate of the era when it was written? My guess is 1950-1970. Was it in English? Was it in a magazine, or in an anthology? The plot feels familiar to me, and I *think* I might've read it in the mid 70s or early 80s.

Comment: Likely duplicate of:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189642/story-about-computer-circuit-that-writes-music

Comment: I agree with @beischt - it sounds very like "The Macauley Circuit" by Silverberg.

Comment: It was the Macauley Circuit.  I didn't remember the prose being what it was, but the plot was identical.  I'm guessing I must have bought a book of Silverberg short stories around the same time I bought the Philip K. Dick one.